# Unable to get the Firebase to invoke the observe/observeSingleEvent callback

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get a user corresponding to an event

I have a list of Events

```
let eventsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference.child("Events")
```

I have a list of Users

```
let usersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference.child("Users")
```

My Event and User model is as below

- Events

  - Event1

    - eventHost: user1_uid
  - Event2

    - eventHost: user2_uid
- Users

  - User1

    - email: email1
  - User2

    - email: email2

The following callback (in the Event model) is never invoked:

```
if let userKey = eventData["eventHost"] as? String {
  userRef = usersRef.child(userKey)
  userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    ...           
  })
}
```

I can confirm that I have not enabled disk persistence and that user uid is available. Is there anything I am doing obviously wrong?

======
EDIT: The simplified event model

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class Event {

    // event metadata
    private var _eventId: String!
    private var _eventHost: User!

    var eventId: String {
        return _eventId
    }

    var eventHost: User {
        return _eventHost
    }

    init(eventId: String, eventData: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        self._eventId = eventId

        if let userKey = eventData["eventHost"] as? String {
            let usersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users")
            let userRef = usersRef.child(userKey)
            print(userRef) 
            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print("USERY: \(snapshot.key)")
                if let userDict = snapshot.value! as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                    let id = snapshot.key
                    self._eventHost = User(userId: id, userData: userDict)
                }
            })
        }

    }
}
```

The `print(userRef)` resolves to

```
https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/Users/AFHpS3npOga4tfj10GS2HGeT9uJ3`
```

which is a valid object in my Firebase structure. Snippet of Firebase User structure

```
  "AFHpS3npOga4tfj10GS2HGeT9uJ3" : {
    "email" : "test@gmail.com",
    "firstName" : "Wilma",
    "lastName" : "Flintstone",
    "profileImageUrl" : "http://images.iimg.in/c/569f4771c45d324bda8b4660-4-501-0-1453279096/google/user-icon-png-pnglogocom.img",
    "provider" : "Firebase",
    "userId" : "AFHpS3npOga4tfj10GS2HGeT9uJ3"
  },
```

Comment: I want to help, but I don't see anything that is obviously wrong. I assume when you say the callback is never invoked, you put a breakpoint in it?

Comment: @JenPerson Yes I put a breakpoint in, and it does not get there

Comment: If you print something in your observe function, will that execute?

Comment: @J.Doe No, it is not going in at all. I do see it print once in a while, but have been unable to put a finger on how to get it to do consistently

Comment: More information is needed: Does the *if let userKey = code* get called? If you put a breakpoint at self._eventId and manually step through the code, one line at a time, on what line does it stop working?

Comment: @Jay Yes, it gets called. When I step through the debugger, it goes to the line with _userRef.observeSingleEvent_ and then skips to _})_ line. The code within the callback does not get executed. The complete model file is [here](https://github.com/themoose3/Recreo/blob/master/Recreo/Event.swift#L133)

Comment: Excellent. Right before the *userRef.observeSingleEvent* line add *print(userRef)*, step through the code again, and examine what is printed by that line. Cross check the path that's printed with your Firebase Structure to see if the path exists. You can add that path to your question (click the edit link below your question) as well so we can see it. Oh - can you include a snippet of your Firebase structure as well? Firebase console->Three dots on right->Export JSON.

Comment: @Jay thanks for your patience! I have made the edits to the question as asked.

Comment: Two questions: is the parent node Users or users (no capital) and also, look at the posted answer with code I added. Change your observe code by adding the withCancel block and run it. See if you get any errors in the Xcode console.

Comment: It skips the withCancel block as well. We could use either Users or users. There are other people working with 'users' and I did not want to block them by making any changes

Comment: I meant in your actual Firebase structure - you only included the child node. Is the parent node Users or users?

Comment: @Jay, I have added both in the Firebase structure with duplicate information, in this case the parent node is Users. Am I making sense?

Comment: Oh. *let usersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference.child("Users")* should be *let usersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users")* - add the parens to reference()

Comment: yes, my bad, that was fixed when running the code. I only didnt update the SO post

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into a new project, along with your Firebase structure, and it worked. Something else must be causing the issue. Perhaps the FIRDatabase reference? Maybe the GoogleService-Info.plist file is messed up?

Comment: Thanks @Jay. I have come to believe it is maybe due to the way I am setting up events when I call it from the viewDidLoad. I will dig into it more and post a reply if I find something. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

can you take a look at the rules of your firebase database :

It should be something like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

in order to let non authenticated people read / write data you should do the following :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

From the code you post I don't see any problem ...
If this doesn't work please post more code and tell us what you plan to do exactly so we can better help you.

**Edit**: To go along with the above suggestion, adding a cancel block to the observe function will reveal if there's a rule issue. If the user cannot access the node, the Xcode console will print 'Permission Denied'

```
userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print("USERY: \(snapshot.key)")
    if let userDict = snapshot.value! as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
        let id = snapshot.key
        self._eventHost = User(userId: id, userData: userDict)
    }
}, withCancel: { error in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
})
```

Comment: Yes, it is set to let non authenticated people read/write data. I have edited the post to include the relevant/simplified parts of the event model. The complete code is posted [here](https://github.com/themoose3/Recreo/blob/master/Recreo/Event.swift#L133)

Comment: your code is correct , could you try to add keepSynced(true) and execute again ?

Comment: I believe that is only when you have persistence enabled? In either case, adding it does not help